# Weird Rounded Corners in Chrome/Safari

Tags: google-chrome, css

I have a rounded corner issue I need help with.  Here is the HTML generated (its in Wordpress):

```
<div class="deal_thumbnail clearfix">
<a href="page.html" title="Read More">
<img width="140" height="110" src="image.jpg" alt="read more" title="Read more" /></a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.deal_thumbnail
{
    float:left;
    width: 150px; 
}
.deal_thumbnail img
{
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 48px;    
}
```

If I set that last 48px to 18px it shows fine in FF, does not round at all in Chrome/Safari (square edges).

If I leave it as is at 48px, it makes a huge smoothly rounded corner (as it should) in FF, here's what I get in Chrome/Safari:
[image: eWeird Corner in Chrome/Safari]

Any thoughts on why I'm not getting anything at 18px, and getting odd corners at 48px in Chrome/Safari while all's well in FF?

Comment: Recently I've started having issues with Chrome not rendering rounded borders with a consistent thickness too. I'm guessing they've got some -webkit-border-radius bugs right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.deal_thumbnail
{
    float:left;
    width: 150px; 
}
.deal_thumbnail img
{
    float:left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px;    
}
```